# What is phpmyadmin access URL after installed from webmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, webmin

I just installed phpmyadmin module from webmin but I can't find any resources which url can be accessed.
My webmin version is 1.550 running on Ubuntu 10.10 with Apache2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
Just have to add following lines in Apache.conf file

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```